# First-child and last-child pseudo property with CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to create styles with first-child and last-child items but I encountered a problem.

When I use first-child, because there is strong item just before, the style isn't apply. But my last-child work fine.

HTML:

```
<br />
<h2 class="title_block">Info <strong>1</strong>
    <span class="title_block_info">+2</span>
    <span class="title_block_info">+1</span>
</h2>​
```

CSS:

```
h2 .title_block_info,
h2 strong {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
h2 .title_block_info:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
h2 .title_block_info:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}​
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/mYKRW/

Anyone know why this came about?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have a "strong" tag as the first child, not the `title_block_info` class you were going for. `first-child` only works if it is in fact the first child of an element.

This works

```
<h2 class="title_block">
    <span class="title_block_info">+2</span>
    <span class="title_block_info">+1</span>
</h2>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYKRW/1/

---

If you need that strong text in there, you could try this, notice how I wrapped your two span tages in another span tag. This will allow you to use first-child and last-child

```
h2 .title_block_info,
h2 strong {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
h2 span .title_block_info:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
h2 span .title_block_info:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}​
```

```
<h2 class="title_block">
    Info <strong>1</strong>
    <span>
      <span class="title_block_info">+2</span>
      <span class="title_block_info">+1</span>
    </span>
</h2>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYKRW/6/

---

Lastly you could use the [`first-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstoftype) pseudo class if you want to keep your html exactly as you want, and just change your css.

```
h2 .title_block_info,
h2 strong {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
h2 .title_block_info:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
h2 .title_block_info:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYKRW/9/

Comment: right you are, I was in a hurry. Wife kicking me off the computer to go to soccer ... thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

The `:first-child` pseudo-class selects the first matching element from the selector `.title_block_info` ***if*** it's *also* the `:first-child` of the parent element; as you note this doesn't work because there's another element that's the first-child of the parent element.

In your case you could either remove the `strong` element that's taking the `:first-child` position in the DOM, or you could use, instead, the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
h2 .title_block_info:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mYKRW/5/).

If your HTML is going to remain similarly predictable (the `.title_block_info` element will *always* follow the `:first-child` element) you could, instead:

```
h2 :first-child + .title_block_info {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mYKRW/10/).

References:

- [`:first-of-type` pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo).
- [`:first-of-type` compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t34).

Comment: Just for the sake of consistency, match it with `:last-of-type`. The compatibility is exactly the same as `:last-child`.